# AS3 - Find words separated by space and hash

Tags: regex, actionscript-3

I'm using a RegExp that finds words with a hash in front such as **#example** .

If there is a link in a text with a hash like *example.com/#about* it comes to problems. So how to extend it to find only words that have also a **space** in front of the **#**? (E.g.: hello #world)

```
var regex:RegExp = /#[^#.,:;!?\s]+(?= #|$)/g;
```

Thanks. Uli

Comment: What exactly do you need to match? According to current description, `/ #(\w+)/g` should work, but it looks too simple

Comment: Found it: `/[\s]#[^#.,:;!?\s]+(?= #|$)/g;` This part was missing: `[\s]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably need something telling it that the space should be an actual space.  I think for you it is going to be something like `/[\s]#` instead of using just `/ #`